# Why won't my transparant 'second' background image center?

Tags: html, css

I want to place a PNG with some transparency (a white column) over a tiled background on a webpage. It should stretch/tile out vertically (not horizontally) over the whole page.  I'm just using CSS and HTML. I'm guessing my understanding of DIV's and CSS is lacking, for which I apologize.
Here's what I have, as a result of a lot of fiddling:

```
body { 
    background-image:url(bin/back.png);
    background-position:left bottom;
}
#second-background {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(bin/column.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y ;
}
```

It's being displayed but I can't get it centered and on top of that it displaces the rest of my content. I've read through how-to-recreate-silverbacks-parallax-effect on thinkvitamin, but I can't get it to work myself.

[Here's](http://joon.be/helena) a link to a demo where you can see it in action.

Comment: I don't fully understand why this doesn't work:
body { 
    background-image:url(bin/back.png);
    background-position:left bottom;
}
#second-background {
    background-image: url(bin/column.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y ;
}
instead it just snaps around the content...

Comment: Is your the content supposed to be aligned left, or is it supposed to be centered?

Comment: it's supposed to be centered. It's almost working now, with just  {width: 100%; background: url(bin/column.png) repeat-y center top} in the second-background tag. But it only stretches to the bottom of the content div, not the bottom of the page. {Height 100%} make it disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but I think it'll work out:

Firstly, add this to near the top of your CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0
}
```

- On `#second-background`, add `width: 100%`.
- On `#second background`, either add `background-position: center top`, or scrap all of your `background-` properties and replace them with this: `background: url(bin/column.png) repeat-y center top`.

Tested in Firefox, with Firebug.

If you would like me to explain why these changes work, just ask.

Comment: As mentioned above, I've tried your code, and it works... almost. The image stretches but not over all the page, just until the end of the content div. If there is a quick and clean explanation that you have i mind, I would be grateful, but I can try to reverse-engineer it as well ;)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your responses. Perhaps if you put your current version live, and explained again, I'll be able to understand.

Comment: Yes, sorry for failing to communicate. Here's an updated version: http://joon.be/helena/ You see the white vertical stripe, it's centered (yay!), the content is in the right place (yay!), but it (the stripe) doesn't stretch all the way to the bottom (NOT yay!).

Comment: Add `height: 100%` to `html, body` and also to `#second-background`. Then it looks right in Firefox, however your site is not centered in IE8 at the moment.

Comment: This did it. Thanks a bunch, I'll figure the IE8 one out later.

Comment: No problem. Quickly looking, it seems IE8 is in "Quirks mode" because of your choice of doctype. I hope that helps when it comes to fixing it in IE.

Comment: Hmmm... still not 100%. When I moved the top image down, the white stripe follows... http://joon.be/helena/

Comment: Move the top image down by using `padding` instead of `margin`. Don't forget to accept again if that works ;)

Comment: It works now, but it creates an unnecessary vertical scroll bar; the white stripe is now taller than the screen. I can put a overflow:hidden in the body, but then I also can't scroll if the window is too small. link updated http://joon.be/helena/. This is what I want it to look like, only without the scrollbar. Thanks so much for your help so far, and I won't forget :)

Comment: I should have been clearer. You were supposed to change `margin` to `padding` on `#header`. So, remove the `padding` from `#second-background`, and change `margin` to `padding` on `#header`.

Comment: oh wow, major brainfart on my end. Just woke up. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to set a fixed width on `#second-background`. Otherwise, with no content in it, it has no width.

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I didn't read your question thoroughly. Let me check out the demo and investigate further.

**Edit 2:** Ok, if you want the white column image over the whole page and centered, then you'll need to set `#second-background` to `width: 100%;` and `background-position: center top;`. This will also allow `#inner-body` to center correctly.

Let me know if this isn't what you were going for.